Where can I find a switch to alternate connections between two pairs of two wires?
I have a small electrical device that communicates with USB-C power bricks and selects a voltage. (This product if anyone's wondering.) You select the voltage by bridging a specific pair of two contacts on the PCB. I have two desired voltages I would like to switch between with a switch (or button if that works too). So, I was wondering if there's any switch that can alternate between connecting one pair of four wires. Here's an image to help explain:

Also, I know that the device supports selecting voltages via I2C but I would prefer to not have to use a microcontroller.

the red and blue wires are both connected to ground ... you only need an SPDT switch

it is unknown what happens if you flip the switch live ... it may re-negotiate the output voltage ... the output may rise to 20 V after one contact opens and before the second contact closes

Good point. I’ll be sure to unplug it before flipping the switch. As for them both being connected to ground, how did you figure that out?

searched through the info on the adafruit site ... found a schematic diagram

The generalized question here is great, if you ignore the small details. The core of it is "What do engineers call this type of switch?", a good question since it's a bit convoluted.

Certainly, there are great number of switches which can do this.
One of the most common kinds of switch is the Double Pole Double Throw switch (DPDT) also called Dual Pole Dual Throw or Two Pole Changeover and many other variants. It will do exactly what you want.  You can find them in all varieties: slide switches, toggle switches with a lever, push switches.
You have to make sure it's break-before-make, which means that it disconnects everything before the new connection is made.  (This is the usual kind.)

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
In your particular case (because RED and BLUE are connected together on your board), you can use just one pole:

simulate this circuit

Also referred to as a Double Pole Double Throw (DPDT; DPST is a typo) switch. Make sure it's non-shorting, most of them are.

Thanks for the quick response! I’ve noticed most push buttons for breadboards have four pins. Does that mean they are likely a DPDP switch?

No, those are usually momentary SPST switches with two pins for each terminal.

Gotcha, thanks for the help!

@Anders_ A non-shorting switch would also be known as a break-before-make switch.

according to the published documentation
https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/124712

The right side pads are all interconnected and the left side pads select a resistor,
So you could use a simpler single pole doiuble switch for this task.
Or possibly simpler bridge the pads pads for 12V and and use a single throw switch to add a resistor in parallel reduce the 10K down to 6k to get 9V operation. (the resistor you want is 15K)
Solder the 15K in series with a switch and connect both to the 5V pads.

A 4-terminal SPDT toggle switch would do.

Image credit: Indiamart
Here's the schematic.

